# Using C preprocessor macros for function naming idiomatic?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a Scheme interpreter. For each built-in type (integer, character, string, etc) I want to have the read and print functions named consistently:

```
READ_ERROR Scheme_read_integer(FILE *in, Value *val);
READ_ERROR Scheme_read_character(FILE *in, Value *val);
```

I want to ensure consistency in the naming of these functions

```
#define SCHEME_READ(type_) Scheme_read_##type_
#define DEF_READER(type_, in_strm_, val_) READ_ERROR SCHEME_READ(type_)(FILE *in_strm_, Value *val_)
```

So that now, instead of the above, in code I can write

```
DEF_READER(integer, in, val) 
{ 
 // Code here ...
}

DEF_READER(character, in, val) 
{
 // Code here ...
}
```

and

```
if (SOME_ERROR != SCHEME_READ(integer)(stdin, my_value)) do_stuff(); // etc.
```

Now is this considered an unidiomatic use of the preprocessor? Am I shooting myself in the foot somewhere unknowingly? Should I instead just go ahead and use the explicit names of the functions?

If not are there examples in the wild of this sort of thing done well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this done extensively in a project, and there's a severe danger of foot-shooting going on.

The problem happens when you try to maintain the code.  Even though your macro-ized function definitions are all neat and tidy, under the covers you get function names like `Scheme_read_integer`.  Where this can become an issue is when something like `Scheme_read_integer` appears on a crash stack.  If someone does a search of the source pack for `Scheme_read_integer`, they won't find it. This can cause great pain and gnashing of teeth ;)

If you're the only developer, and the code base isn't that big, and you remember using this technique years down the road and/or it's well documented, you may not have an issue.  In my case it was a *very* large code base, poorly documented, with none of the original developers around.  The result was much tooth-gnashing.

I'd go out on a limb and suggest using a C++ template, but I'm guessing that's not an option since you specifically mentioned C.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks. I can see how auto-generated names would yield a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Just one note: I'm not sure how this would translate into a C++ template. I'd use either static member functions or namespaces to get the equivilent `Scheme_read_integer(in, val)` => `Scheme::Integer::read(in, val)`

Comment: It'd be more like `template<typename T> Scheme_stuff(FILE *in, T val)` which would define a class, with a `read` member that take the type parameter, `T` as a parameter.  It gets a little more verbose, but it reduces some future maintenance problems. I'd have to think more about it, but the static functions would work and still be self-annotating.

Answer (score 1):

I'm usually a big fan of macros, but you should probably consider inlined wrapper functions instead. They will add negligible runtime overhead and will appear in stack backtraces, etc., when you're debugging.